# IPC Troubleshooting

Tags: .net, windows, debugging, ipc

What is the best way to troubleshoot IPC?

Are there any tools/tricks to determine problems (without requesting the source code)?

I have two, third party components. The IPC server config and client config seems correct. Yet the two components don't want to communicate. One component throwing a null object exception, which I believe is due to something wrong in the remoting configuration....

Comment: Focus on "what's the best way to ask a question on a forum".  Nobody can help you with only a "doesn't work" diagnostic.  You've got config, you've got a stack trace.  Use them to document your problem.

Comment: There's only a single way of doing IPC in .NET? Otherwise my first question would be what kind of IPC are you actually using, I know a dozen of different ways of doing IPC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have PDB files from components installed try getting DUMP with [ADPLUS](http://blogs.msdn.com/johan/archive/2007/01/11/how-to-install-windbg-and-get-your-first-memory-dump.aspx).
[DebugDiag 1.1 or Windbg, which one should I use? and how do I gather memory dumps](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/05/21/debugdiag-1-1-or-windbg-which-one-should-i-use-and-how-do-i-gather-memory-dumps.aspx)
Other info for mem leak finding :
[Reverse Engineering and Debugging Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/ntdebugging/archive/2008/09/25/some-of-our-favorite-debugging-related-links.aspx)
[All the Ways to Capture a Dump...](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfedev/archive/2008/09/26/all-the-ways-to-capture-a-dump.aspx)
[Troubleshooting Software Problems: A Scientific Approach](http://blogs.msdn.com/debuggingtoolbox/archive/2008/07/03/troubleshooting-software-problems-a-scientific-approach.aspx)
[Two Minute Drill: Configuring a Debugger using Image File Execution Options](http://blogs.technet.com/askperf/archive/2008/12/12/two-minute-drill-configuring-a-debugger-using-image-file-execution-options.aspx)
[Slides and resources for TechED presentations about debugging .NET issues with Windbg](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/11/21/slides-and-resources-for-teched-presentations-about-debugging-net-issues-with-windbg.aspx)
[background tool : ExcpHook Exception Monitor](http://gynvael.coldwind.pl/?id=148&lang=en)

Comment: i don't have the PDBs - but stepping through so test calls to the service I have identified the some exception that one of the 3rd party components are hiding. grrrrrr